# VSTO - Determine if Document is recovered in Word Addin

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, recovery, office-addins

My word addin writes some stuff to the document in the AddIn_Startup event (of course under some conditions ;-) ). 
When a document is recovered, most of the time there is recovered text in the document and I dont want to write in the recovered file with my generated text.

So I need to know how it is possible to determine if the ActiveDocument is recovered.

I am using C# and Visual Studio Tools for Office 2010.

Comment: Can you show us some code ?

Comment: Well, I just need a condition befor i write the text to the document for example

if(Application.ActiveDocument.IsInRecoveryMode)

But i cant find anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

The Word object model doesn't provide anything for that. But you can use CustomDocumentProperties for adding a marker that you have already added the text to the document. See the [CustomDocumentProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195603(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Document class for more information. It returns a DocumentProperties collection that represents all the custom document properties for the specified document. Before adding a text you can check out the value of custom property and decide whether you need to add the text or not.

Comment: That's correct, but what if the user writes some standard text without using  the addin. The Word instance crashes and next time he starts word under the conditions my addin starts to work. 

My addin starts to works when i open word from another program i am working on.
So if someone starts Word and writes some text and the instance crashes, next time the file will be recovered from Word.
But if he starts Word next time from my programm, The addin would write the text to the recovered file which has nothing to do with the generated text.

Comment: In that case you have to search for the text in the document. Nothing can be done.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I feared. Thanks!